# ssh -A still not allowing git pull

Tags: ssh, git, public-key

We have a setup where our git server needs the publickeys to authenticate in order to push or pull. I am trying to do so on one of our servers and can't figure out why it isn't working. I have searched and searched and everything I have found says to just run `ssh -A` when logging into the server and that should forward what is needed to allow git operations, but it isn't working.

On my local machine, I can cd into a directory, run `git push origin master` type in my password for ~/.ssh/id_rsa and it works perfectly.

When logging into the server I tried using `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` putting in my password, then running `ssh -A [user]@[server]` and it logs in fine, I then cd into the directory and run `git pull` to which I am given `permission denied (publickey)`

I can't figure out why it is not allowing me to push or pull from the server, it works locally, and I am using the -A flag when ssh-ing into the server, but always `permission denied (publickey)`

Hopefully someone much more skilled in server stuff can see that I am just doing something wrong and it's an easy fix. Thank you all, I appreciate the time and help

Answer (score 0):

Use `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git pull` to get verbose output from `ssh`.

Comment: Run that on the server after I ssh into the server?

Comment: @NeglectedSanity you run this instead of plain `git pull`

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't understand your setup completely, but in general I can recommend using a [SSH config file](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) for such use cases.

For example if your server name is `my-server.com`, it could look like the following:

```
Host my-server.com
 HostName my-server.com
 Port 22
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

It will prompt you for your passphrase for the private key.